# Sort Custom Post Type Archive by Taxonomy Term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

What is the best method (as of 3.1 or 3.2 beta) to sort a custom post type archive by a given taxonomy term?

I'm trying to make a staff page and I want to sort employees by department. So the taxonomy would be `staff` and the terms to sort would be `sales` and `support`.

I tried `query_posts` and `WP_Query` but perhaps I messed up the arg array...

Comment: For mutually exclusive terms use post meta not taxonomies. Sorting is easy then.

Comment: I thought of using post meta but as I understood it taxonomies are for grouping large numbers of posts within a few variables. If I can't find a good way to do it with taxonomies I will definitely have to go this route...

Comment: One object may have more than one taxon from each taxonomy. That’s the basic difference to post meta values. The other: Queries for post meta touch just two tables, not three like for taxonomies.

Comment: old post, but for anyone looking this is how i solved it:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38075/group-custom-post-type-in-a-page-by-its-taxomony-tag/58802#58802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question - I'm fairly sure you can't do this just using wp_query.

You'll need to either add a posts_groupby filter, or just query the database directly. This previous question and answer might be helpful

[Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy)