# Group Custom post type in a page by its taxomony tag

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

I hope i can write a clear question since i got confused trying to solve this...

I got a custom post type... that custom post type has taxomony (category like)
and i want to **return a structure like this** in a page that show all posts of
that post type..

--------------------------------------------- DESIRED STURCTURE

taxomony category name (Example: new york)
  - post one (assosicated with new york category)
  - post two (assosicated with new york category)
  - post three (assosicated with new york category)

taxomony category name (Example: Washington DC)
  - post one (assosicated with Washington DC category)
  - post two (assosicated with Washington DC category)
  - post three (assosicated with Washington DC category)
  - post four (assosicated with Washington DC category)
  - post Five (assosicated with Washington DC category)

taxomony category name (Example: SomeCity)
  - post one (assosicated with SomeCity category)
  - post two (assosicated with SomeCity category)

**This is the code i have now:**

```
        <div class="pageContent portfolioPage">

            <!--=STR== PAGE TITLE ===-->
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>   
                <h1 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            <!--=END== PAGE TITLE ===-->

            <!--=STR== OUR CLIENTS ===-->                   
            <?php 
            /*
                query_posts(array( 
                    'post_type' => 'vacationrental',
                    'showposts' => 100
                ) );  
            */
            $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'vacationrental',
            'post_per_page' => 100,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC'
            ));             

            ?>


            <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="vacationRentalBox">
                    <div class="vacationRentalBox-inner">

                        <?php
                        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large');  
                        $image_url = $image_url[0];  
                        // $googleMapsUrl = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'vacationrental_map', true ); // GOOGLE MAPS URL
                        ?>              

                        <div class="vacationRentalBar">
                            <div class="vacationRentalName"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div> 

                            <div class="thumbsingle">
                            <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" class="lightbox"><?php the_post_thumbnail('testimonialPage'); ?></a>
                            </div>      

                            <div class="vacationRentalDescription"><?php dynamic_excerpt(315); ?></div> 

                            <div class="vacationRentalExtraInfo">
                                <div class="vacationRentalReadMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php _e('Read More &rarr;' ,'sagive'); ?></a></div>                             
                            </div>
                            <br style="clear: both;" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;?>
            <!--=END== OUR CLIENTS ===-->                           

            <br style="clear: both;" />
        </div>
```

.
I managed to get the list of taxomonies categories using this:

```
$terms = get_terms("locations");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

But i dont know how to integrate that into the loop / structure
Would really apreaciate your help since i am stuck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I follow your question correctly you could use a nested query loop, that is looping through your taxonomy terms and then doing a WP_Query loop for each one.

There is a more complicated approach using custom SQL and a filter but the following example is what I would go for:

```
$terms = get_terms("locations");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'vacationrental',
            'post_per_page' => 100,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id
                )
            )
        ));
        // the loop
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            // do loop content
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        endwhile;
        // reset $post so that the rest of the template is in the original context
        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to reset before the endwhile? Otherwise I agree, would do it the same way, +1

Comment: Yeah I guess it wouldn't hurt - the post stuff is getting overridden in the `$loop->the_post();` bit though so I left it outside. I've not tested it mind you.

Comment: 10x a lot (really!) :) - aprroved and up'd 1 - have a gr8 day... i need to wait hour but you got the bounty

Comment: @SagiveSEO cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is old and you have a solution, but i was trying to do the same thing.  here is how i ended up doing it w/ SQL voodoo patched together from a couple of places, but mostly:

[Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy#answer-14313) and

[how to group custom post type posts by custom taxonomy terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12369/how-to-group-custom-post-type-posts-by-custom-taxonomy-terms#answer-12384)

first the query voodoo:

```
function wpa_38075( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( !is_post_type_archive( 'vacationrental' )) return $clauses;


        //join term_relationships to posts, and term_relationships to term_taxonomy and term_taxonomy to terms
        $clauses['join'] .= "LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)" ;

        //look for posts with and without a subject term
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = 'locations' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";

        $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";

        //remove limits
        $clauses['limits'] = "";

        //group posts by term name
        $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";

    return $clauses;
}


add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpa_38075', 10, 2 );
```

and then in your template:

```
<?php 

$prev = ''; //not set yet

if (have_posts()) :

    echo "<ul>";

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  


    $subhead =  array_shift(wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'subject', array("fields" => "names")));
    $subhead = $subhead ? $subhead : __('Uncategorized','yourtextdomain');

    if($subhead != $prev) { ?>
        <h3 class="subhead"><?php echo $subhead;?></h3>
    <?php } ?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>" title="<?php echo __('Permalink to', 'peterwade') . ' ' . get_the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>

    <?php 

    $prev = $subhead; //cache the previous tax term

endwhile; 
echo "</ul>";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: cool @helgatheviking - looks goods... would try it and thanks for sharing

Comment: sure thing.  i hope it helps the next person who comes along with the same issue.