# Create a Metabox that behaves Like a Taxonomy Box

Tags: post-meta

I need to show all my custom articles on an archive page but grouped/sorted by subject.

So that the result is somewhat like

Subject A:

- A Sample Post
- Another Sample Post

Subject B:

- List item

A Post About Bacon

and so on?

I've read some related posts on here  [17155](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17155/sort-custom-post-type-archive-by-taxonomy-term) and [14306](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy) and have come to the conclusion that this type of grouping must be done with post meta.  However a simple metabox with a text input isn't as friendly as the checkboxes of the category metabox.... nor the tag box with its (choose from most popular tags option).

So I am looking for advice, what is the best way to get the best of both worlds?  I'd like to enforce selection into only 1 subject, but I'd like to be able to see what other subjects have already been used.

Can I replace the category metabox so that it uses radio buttons instead of checkboxes and then save the category info as post meta on save?  where to start?

Comment: Should the list be extendable by the user? You might need a [datalist](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_datalist_tag.cfm) for this.

Comment: i'd like the user to be able add a term.  i think i am going to pursue this route: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-taxonomies/ am trying to wrap it into a full-fledged plugin at the moment.

Comment: i made a pretty good start on making that a plugin: https://github.com/helgatheviking/Radio-Buttons-for-Taxonomies i'm sure it needs some testing before i can add it to the repo.  i like the idea of datalists though!  more to learn i guess.

Comment: Would it not be preferable to add an additional taxonomy? And then add the taxonomy to the post type(s)

Comment: @BarryCarlyon - i ended up doing that.  the trouble is you can't sort a query by taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up building a plugin that enforces radio buttons for any taxonomy.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/

for the project in question i will probably also save the taxonomy as meta.  sucks that i need/want half the ability of taxonomy (knowing other available terms, etc), but need the sorting by meta.

Comment: The other option would be to create the taxonomy without a public UI and then build your own meta box for it.

Comment: the plugin removes the normal metabox and replaces it w/ my custom one.

Comment: Lovely. (I didn't follow the link to go look at the code :-P )