# How to get the posts of a custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I hope someone will help me:

I have a **Custom Post Type** (Movie) with its **custom taxonomy** (Producer), this taxonomy has its **own terms**, for example 'WarnerBros'.

How I can get all the posts of my term (WarnerBros)?

I have this but doesn't work yet.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'movie',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'producer',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'WarnerBros',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

After playing with the code I resolved the problem, I will share my code for someone with the same issue:

```
 
$type = 'Movie';  // Custom Post Type Name
$tag =  'WarnerBros'; // Your Term
```

$args =  array(
        'post_type' => $type, 
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC', 
                'tax_query'=>array(
                    array(
            'taxonomy'=>'Producer', //Taxonomy Name 
            'field'=>'slug',
            'terms'=>array($tag)
                            ))
                    );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    if(is_object_in_term($post->ID,'Taxonomy_Name','Your_Term')) // Producer and WarnerBros {

`echo '<div id="YourID">'; echo the_title(); echo '</div>';       

}  endwhile;`

Comment: I have been trying with to many examples but anything works.

Comment: Please don't post code blocks in comments, instead click "edit" in your question and then click the `{}` to enter your code in a [formatted way](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). This makes it easier for users to see what you've tried and can maybe modify it to fix your issue!

Comment: Sorry, now is fixed ;)

Answer (score 2):

This question has different answers in this specific Wordpress question, they may be of help:

[Display all posts in a custom post type, grouped by a custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32902/display-all-posts-in-a-custom-post-type-grouped-by-a-custom-taxonomy)

Personally I used this method that worked for me just fine:

```
$terms = get_terms('tax_name');
$posts = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $posts[$term->name] = get_posts(array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post_type', 'tax_name' => $term->name ));
}
```

Editing it to your scenario this should work:

```
$terms = get_terms('producer');
$posts = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $posts[$term->name] = get_posts(array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'movie', 'tax_name' => $term->name ));
}
```

Now you can get your posts:

```
print_r($posts["WarnerBros"]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, maybe because the snippet doesn't have the term name.

Comment: I have edited the answer to meet your variables. Don't expect too much that the answers have exactly your same variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'movie',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'producer',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'WarnerBros',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See more at [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: It seems that doesn't work, should I to use my term slug? Or maybe call other function like: `<?php (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have a custom post type **plays** and under the taxonomy **genre** you want to find all the posts with the category **comedy**

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'plays', /*Post type (plays)*/
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'genre', /*Taxonomy to search (genre)*/
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'comedy', /*Search category for (comedy)*/
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```