# Best way to group posts based on custom post type terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have been trying to group custom posts based on the taxonomy terms as shown in [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/taxonomy-archives-list-posts-by-taxonomys-terms--cms-20045). Here is another similar post:

- [Display all posts in a custom post type, grouped by a custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32902/display-all-posts-in-a-custom-post-type-grouped-by-a-custom-taxonomy?rq=1)

That does the job but I am worried about the number of `WP_Query` being looped. What if we had  somewhat larger number of terms? In such case, there will be repetitive database queries.

Is there any better approach to get the same result.

I am thinking of using WordPress transient but that I guess is another side. Is doing raw sql queries any better?

Comment: Good morning! Please don't post such questions on meta. Or grab a morning-coffee before posting if you already knew :)

Comment: Was a mistake. Sorry for that :) Haven't been using stackexchange for quite a time. Thanks for migrating.

Comment: I have a ton of posts using `usort` to sort posts according to post type, taxonomy terms and custom fields. Feel free to search my answers for `usort`. The solution you linked to is very expensive :-)