# Loop with Custom Post Type Taxonomies and Interstitial Code

Tags: loop

Have a custom post type "videos" with custom post type categories.

Can do a simple loop that shows all videos from all categories without a problem. Can also limit to just show videos from a single category.

What I wish to do is show all videos from category x (in order of date) and then show all videos from category y (in order of date) and in front of each category of videos would be a header text including that category name such as.

For instance this would show all videos in category 5:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
$args = array(
 'post_type'      => 'Videos',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'order'          => 'DESC',
 'orderby'        => 'ID',
 'tax_query' => array(
     array(
         'taxonomy' => 'videos_category',
         'field'    => 'id',
         'terms'    => 382,
     ),
 ),

 );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<h2>Blue Videos</h2>
  <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

  <h3><?php the_title(''); ?></h3>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <p>No Posts</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I could duplicate the above with the second one using the other category id but sure there is a much simpler more elegant way.

Comment: 1. show all videos from category x  
  2. show all videos from category y
  3. in front of each category of videos would be a header text

Which one is the question?

Comment: Yes, those are all part of the question. Doing each of those individually as noted isn't a problem, but attempting to do it all at once cleanly. So ultimately as noted there would be a video page that pulls in all videos from a custom post type, separated by categories visually and each category would have a header noting the name of that category.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after determining the right terms to search for here:

[Display all posts in a custom post type, grouped by a custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32902/display-all-posts-in-a-custom-post-type-grouped-by-a-custom-taxonomy)