# Display all posts in a custom post type, grouped by a custom taxonomy. How to sort the posts alphabetically and the terms by ID?

Tags: wp-query, sort, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type called as `books` with taxonomy named as `genre`. Inside the `genre` there are a number of terms such as `horror`, `romance,`comedy`, etc.

I want to display them in the archive page, grouped by each terms. So I use [Chip Bennet's fantastic code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40117/13291).

However, I have problem with the sorting.

The code sorts the terms according to its alphabetical names, and the posts according to the recentness. So it appears like this:

- Comedy

  - Newest book
  - Not so new book
  - Old book
- Horror

  - etc the same: newest - not new - old
- Romance
- Sci-fi

Meanwhile, I need it to be sorted differently. I want to sort the terms according to the tag_ID, and the book list according to its alphabetical name. So it should look like this:

- Sci-fi `(tag_ID number 1)`

  - A
  - B
  - C
  - etc
- Romance `(tag_ID number 2)`
- Comedy `(tag_ID number 3)`
- Horror `(tag_ID number 4)`

I tried to mess with the query, so it looks like this

```
$member_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'member',
    'orderby ' => 'name', // sort the books alphabetically
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'member_group',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $member_group_term->slug ),
            'orderby ' => 'ID', // sort the genre according to its ID
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
) );
```

But nothing changes. I checked [Wordpress Codex on `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to make sure but still no avail. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first to sort the genre terms in the other query:

```
$genres = get_terms( 'genre', 'orderby=term_id' );
```

And then on the posts query for each genre (like Chip Bennet's approach):

```
$member_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'member',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'member_group',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $member_group_term->slug ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
) );
```

Comment: Oh so that's where you sort the genre. Thanks! It works for the genre, but I can't still sort the books... it's still sorted by its newness rather than alphabetically. Oddly `'orderby' => 'rand'` works but not `'orderby' => 'name'`...

Comment: and if you try `'orderby' => 'title'` instead?

Comment: Okay, curiously it works with `'orderby' => 'title'` and `'order' => 'ASC'`. Really odd. Thanks @dbeja!

Comment: when you order by name, you're ordering by slug. I don't know if it's related or not. but now it's working :)