# What's the WP way to load remaining custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop

I am displaying custom post types, grouped under their custom taxonomies (basically used @ChipBennett's answer from here: [Display all posts in a custom post type, grouped by a custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32902/display-all-posts-in-a-custom-post-type-grouped-by-a-custom-taxonomy)) for a products section of the site.

But, I'd like to limit the number of products that are initially displayed. Say, show 4, and if there are more than 4 products under that category, then I'd like to add a "load more products" link, which when clicked, loads the remaining products in that category onto the page.

I can do that with some JS (initially showing only the :nth-child(-n+4) while hiding the rest), but I suspect there's a more elegant and a less resource-intensive solution using WP/PHP.

```
<section id="products" class="padd-me">
  <h1 class="heading centered main-color">Our Products</h1>

  <?php
  $productCategories = get_terms( 'product_taxonomy' );
  foreach ( $productCategories as $productCategory ) {
    $productQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_taxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( $productCategory->slug ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ) );

    if ( $productQuery->have_posts() ) {
      ?>
      <div class="product-row">
        <div class="product-title">
          <h3><?php echo $productCategory->name; ?></h3>
        </div>
      <div class="product-pics-wrap">
      <?php
      while ( $productQuery->have_posts() ) {
        $productQuery->the_post();
        $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <div class="product-pic" style="background-image:url(' <?php echo $backgroundImg[0] ?>');"></div>
        </a>
        <?php
       }
      ?>
        </div>
        <div class="more-products-link-wrap">
          <a class="more-products" href="#">see all products</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
    };
    ?>

    <?php
    // Reset things, for good measure
    $productQuery = null;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
?>
```

Comment: `wp_admin_ajax` hooks https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Further_Reading_-_External_Resources

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your QP Query with  posts_per_page

Read more here at [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

and then, use AJAX to load more on a button click or page scroll.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to limit it to 4 using posts_per_page, but I don't know how to load the rest...