# Combine multiple separate lists into one

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, loop

I have a custom query for my taxonomy of:

```
    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => "issueCompanion", 
            'hide_empty' => false, 
            'fields'=>'all'
        )
    )
```

which returns an array of publications (think along the lines of monthly magazines). I have an advanced custom field on the taxonomy by the name of published_year in which the user types a string of the year the magazine was published in.

In order to get the year on each taxonomy, I run this code within a for loop:

```
$year = get_field('published_year', $term)
```

I'm having trouble combining the two different requests into one loop without one thing or another showing up several times.

I need to create a single page in which I am showing the year, and then list all publications that match that year, like so:

```
2019
  Publication xxx
  Publication xxx
2018
  Publication xxx
  etc.
```

I would be most grateful for any input that helps me combine the two into one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display all posts in a custom post type, grouped by a custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32902/display-all-posts-in-a-custom-post-type-grouped-by-a-custom-taxonomy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multidimensional array to get this format. Please see the example given below:

```
$terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => "issueCompanion", 
        'hide_empty' => false, 
        'fields'=>'all'
    )
)

$multi_arr = array();

foreach($terms as $term){
    $year = get_field('published_year', $term->term_id);
    $multi_arr[$year][] = $term->name;
}
```

When you print this $multi_arr you will get the format you want. So you can manage your code according to this.