# WP_Query orderby taxonomy term value (numeric)

Tags: wp-query

I have this query...

```
<?php 

    $press = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'individual',
        'post_status'   => 'private' 
    ));

    if ($press->have_posts()) : while ($press->have_posts()) : $press->the_post();

?>
```

But my custom post-types are using custom taxonomy with a numeric term value.

My question is there anyway in ordering this query by the term value?

The taxonomy is called 'individual-group'

Any help would be hugely appreciated thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with default WP Core. @heathenJesus talks about meta data not taxonomies. See http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html for a proper solution.

And a more thorough explanation of why this is not something built into Core: [Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy/14309#14309)

Comment: Thanks Evan, I will make sure to create meta keys for this in future if I ever need to order a taxonomy term.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complex query I used to numerically sort and filter the posts query by taxonomy slugs.

```
$my_post_type = 'some_post_type';
$my_term_slug_to_be_used_for_Ordering = 'some_slug';
$my_term_slug_to_be_used_for_Filtering = 'some_other_slug';

$querystr = "
  SELECT 
   $wpdb->posts.*, $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id, 
   (SELECT wpt.slug
        FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy wptt 
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships wptr ON wptt.term_taxonomy_id = wptr.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms wpt ON wpt.term_id = wptt.term_id
        WHERE 
        wptr.object_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND 
        wptt.taxonomy = 'my_term_slug_to_be_used_for_Ordering') AS numeric_column_value

    FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
         INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
         INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id
    WHERE 
         $wpdb->terms.slug = '{$my_term_slug_to_be_used_for_Filtering}' AND
         $wpdb->posts.post_type = '$my_post_type' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'

    ORDER BY numeric_column_value * 1 DESC"; // Actually it is a string so, * 1 for numeric

$r = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in the `orderby` parameter, there is an option called `meta_value_num` which should do exactly what you are looking for.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

---

```
$press = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'individual',
    'post_status'    => 'private',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'individual-group'
));
```

Comment: ... so long as the meta_value actually is a number. There are more than a couple of posts here where people are trying to numerically sort things that aren't numbers :) @heathenJesus, can you provide sample code. Link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: The question specifically stated "custom taxonomy *with a numeric term value.*"

Added a demonstration of using 'meta_value_num'.

Comment: Oh, I know. That was not in any way critical of your answer. I just don't, in general, trust people when they say "numeric". Sometimes it means something like "$100" or "123-04". Those are colloquially numbers but are not numeric to the software. And I work with an office full of people like that so I've learned to specify very carefully.

Comment: Fair enough, @s_ha_dum

Comment: @heathenJesus so you saying I can actually query taxonomy terms the same as querying custom fields? I thought mete keys and registered taxonomy terms were two separate things... For example could I query using your method a category term via 'meta_key' ? I didn't think you could do that...?

Comment: as in `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'category'`? Obviously my category term has to be purely numeric for the orderby function to work of course..