# Get all the contents of taxonomy and sort by term

Tags: php, taxonomy, terms, html

I'm doing this in a page template.

So far, I can query all the contents under my taxonomy.

But I need to sort them in terms of their term. Any idea on how to do this? Providing an example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Apparently that's not possible, see [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87639/wp-query-orderby-taxonomy-term-value-numeric)

Comment: Well that's depressing. I can display each content according to terms. But if the term has more than one content, then it would display X times depending on how many content it has.