# making php value numeric

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, functions, mysql, sql

I used some of this code from this page on Stack Overflow:
[Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy/14313#14313)

It's about the function to be able to sort a query by a taxonomy value. Although it works perfectly, I would want to go one step further.

The value I retrieve from the taxonomy term is a number. If I sort by that number, however, it gives this order: 1 10 11 2 21 22 and so on.

I want it to be sorted 'normally', 1 2 3 5 9 11 15 21 22 etc.

According to google I should add 0 to the value to make it a numeric value, but I don't know where to put it in this code. Somewhere, it should say value + 0. Any idea where I should put it?

It's about this code:

```
function orderby_tax_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $taxonomy == $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) {
            $clauses['join'] .=<<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
SQL;
            $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '{$taxonomy}' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
            $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";
            $clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
            $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'DESC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
        }
    }
    return $clauses;
}

    add_filter('posts_clauses', 'orderby_tax_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: please explain the GROUP_CONCAT usage on the orderby part

Comment: Actually I can't, it's not my own code. It works perfectly, except it doesn't sort 'naturally' (see intro). The thing I am wondering about is why this wouldn't work:

`$clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name+0 ASC) ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more about SQL than WordPress.

If you want to sort your term names as numbers, you can in general try

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms ORDER BY name+0 ASC
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms ORDER BY name*1 ASC
```

or use CAST:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms ORDER BY CAST(name AS SIGNED) ASC
```

where you can use `SIGNED`, `UNSIGNED` or maybe `DECIMAL(10,2)`, just depending on your numbers.

### Update

To test the ordering you can then visit your PHPMyAdmin and run this query:

```
SELECT  tool_terms.name AS tname, tool_posts.* FROM tool_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tool_term_relationships ON tool_posts.ID=tool_term_relationships.object_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tool_term_taxonomy USING (term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tool_terms USING (term_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND tool_posts.post_type = 'landschapselement' 
AND (tool_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR tool_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR tool_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR tool_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND (taxonomy = 'beheerseenheidnummer' OR taxonomy IS NULL) 
GROUP BY object_id 
ORDER BY tool_terms.name+0 ASC, tool_posts.post_title ASC
```

to see if it works where I replaced

```
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(tool_terms.name ORDER BY name ASC) ASC
```

with

```
ORDER BY tool_terms.name+0 ASC, tool_posts.post_title ASC
```

where we order the posts by the taxonomy numeric value, and then the second order is on the post title. I also added the field `tool_terms.name AS tname` to the `SELECT` part. This works on my install.

You can also try to replace

```
$clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
$clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'DESC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
```

with:

```
$clauses['orderby'] = " {$wpdb->terms}.name+0 ";
$clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'DESC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
$clauses['orderby'] = ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC ";
```

Comment: `$clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name+0 ASC) ";
    $clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name*1 ASC) ";`

And the other ones, they all don't work in this situation.

Comment: can you post the generated SQL query?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: there are many SQL profile plugins out there, for example [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mysql-profiler/screenshots/)

Comment: `SELECT tool_posts.* FROM tool_posts LEFT OUTER JOIN tool_term_relationships ON tool_posts.ID=tool_term_relationships.object_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tool_term_taxonomy USING (term_taxonomy_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN tool_terms USING (term_id) WHERE 1=1 AND tool_posts.post_type = 'landschapselement' AND (tool_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR tool_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR tool_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR tool_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (taxonomy = 'beheerseenheidnummer' OR taxonomy IS NULL) GROUP BY object_id ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(tool_terms.name ORDER BY name ASC) ASC`

Comment: `SELECT t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id FROM tool_terms AS t INNER JOIN tool_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN tool_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('beheerseenheidnummer', 'anderesubsidieovereenkomstnummer') AND tr.object_id IN (730, 779, 805, 811, 814, 817, 818, 1641, 1642, 1645, 1646, 1677, 1681, 1804, 1814, 1815, 2093, 2094, 2129, 2130, 2197, 2262, 2283, 2284, 2358, 2370) ORDER BY t.name ASC`

Comment: It seems irrelevent code. What I want is to sort the query by 'beheersnummer'. This is a numerical value that is stored in the custom taxonomy 'beheersnummer'. This code seems to be looping over ALL taxonomies, but I only need 'beheerseenheidnummer. Unfortunately, my knowledge of MySQL is too limited to adjust it.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I replaced it with `$clauses['orderby'] = " {$wpdb->terms}.name+0 ";
$clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'DESC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';`

It didn' work with the following line attached, but when I deleted it it works like a charm! Thanks!
`$clauses['orderby'] = ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC ";`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your query look like this one:

```
"SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN ASCII(RIGHT(`%column_name%`, 1)) > 47 AND ASCII(RIGHT(`%column_name%`, 1)) < 58
THEN LPAD(CONCAT(`%column_name%`,  '-'), 5, '0') 
ELSE LPAD(`%column_name%`, 5, '0') END AS `vsort` 
FROM `%table_name%` ORDER BY `vsort`;"
```

[From this webpage](http://www.mikestowe.com/2010/08/natsort-in-mysql.php)

> Note: you’ll want to replace %column_name% with the ACTUAL column name, and %table_name% with the actual table name.

The result would be like one after PHP's [`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function.