# Sorting main query by custom taxonomy slug

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, wpdb

Is there a way to sort posts by custom taxonomy (shoe_color) ASC|DESC? I would like to do this using `query_posts` and passing the `orderby=shoe_color` into it.

Here is the code I'm trying to work out:

```
function shoe_color_orderby( $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return "(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(slug ORDER BY slug ASC)
        FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy USING (term_taxonomy_id)
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms USING (term_id)
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = object_id
        AND taxonomy = 'shoe_color'
        GROUP BY object_id
    ) ";
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'shoe_color_orderby');
```

Comment: Check this search queries: [`posts_orderby`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bposts_orderby%20%2btaxonomy%20is%3aanswer) and [`pre_get_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bpre_get_posts%20%2btaxonomy%20is%3aanswer)

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy/