# woocommerce - products by category slug?

Tags: categories, slug, woocommerce-offtopic

good morning, I need to display the shop base page in a category layout,meaning first show all the products from category A and beneath it all the products from category B and so on..
I trying to use the built-in woocommerce shortcode -"products by category slug" but instead it displays products by products slug,what is the solution?

here is the shortcode

[product_category category="" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]

thank you

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the relevant shortcode callback code.

Comment: why is woocommerce a tag if those questions are off topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @ChipBennett meant is to show the actual code that is represented by the shortcode, it can be found in the [source](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.1/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php#L127). Take a look at this to see what's behind it - it is a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Aside from that, the problem is - as far as I can tell - that you're misinterpreting what the shortcode does. Especially regarding the `orderby` parameter of `WP_Query`, which is **not** designed to order by category/taxonomy. It is just not part of core and

> this is not something we want in Core. Here's a thorough explanation from Otto:<sup>[1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18616#comment:2)</sup>

Here on WPSE to be exact, as answer to [Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14309/22534).

Comment: hi thank you :) I am trying to understand -  in my virtual shop i  will have only 3 categories shirts shoes and dresses like in a real shop each category should have their own  shelf/department,so lets say i want that category shirts(and its products of course) will always show before category shoes ,where do i put the code for that? and should i use custom fiels type to achive this?

Comment: I guess the easiest way to do this to use multiple loops, which, in your case, equals using the shortcode multiple times.
Of course you've to adapt it to your needs. @takethat

`[product_category category="shirts"] \\display first category  `
`[product_category category="shoes"] \\display second category  `
`[product_category category="dresses"] \\display third category  `

Comment: I understand now - so you have to do it manually for each specific shop (needs),by the way i found a plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/ that helps a little.thank you again.