# Nested loop : wich way/order?

Tags: query, php

Good morning (or evening),

I try to merge in a custom archive (taxonomy-$taxonomy.php) a double (?) query.
Let's try to be clear :

I’d like to display all the posts from a taxonomy.
Ok, it works.

```
//start by fetching the terms for 'progression' taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( 'progression', array(
    'orderby'    => 'asc',
    'hide_empty' => 1
) );
```

And the query

```
// Run a query for each progression
foreach( $terms as $term ) {

     $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('my_custom_post', 'another_custom_post'),
        'progression' => $term->slug,
        );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // output the term name (here "day1", "day2"...)                
    echo $term->name;

    // Start the Loop and output the titles
       while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
           the_title(); 
       endwhile;   

    // use reset postdata to restore original query
    wp_reset_postdata();

} ?>
```

*(of course, I didn't find this by myself... thanks this forum !)*

BUT (that’s the problem)
It displays **every** post with this tax.
However, I would like to restrict my request to another taxonomy.

A second tax 'sport' => volley, tennis, basket...

Individually, it works.
**BUT, as soon as I try to combine the both criterias, I fail miserably.**

*I could write my code (with the second query and args, but it doesn't work, so, is it usefull ?)*
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `tax_query` parameter with a relation to do this,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('my_custom_post', 'another_custom_post'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'progression',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term->slug,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sport',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 1, 2, 3 ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Of course, you'll need arrange `term_id` for the sport taxonomy relation.

You will find more examples and details about the taxonomy parameter in the [WP_Query class reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Hope it helps.

Comment: The <pre>tax_query</pre> will effectively display a list of posts with the written conditions.
But...
I'm trying to order my posts according to a taxonomy (in this case 'progression').
And, I found this article : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy

... which makes me think that I'm perhaps in a wrong direction with my taxonomies (progression). It seems to be more efficient to "play" with custom fields and get_the_meta. Or, make 3 distincts queries (for my 3 days). 
Thanks again !!

Comment: Yes, you can use both tax_query and meta_query in the same query.