# How do I sort posts by custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pre-get-posts, tax-query

I am trying to sort posts by custom taxonomy. I have a custom post type which is `course-cpt` and I have created custom taxonomies within it, I need to sort the courses by `course-level` (which is the taxonomy term) so that it displays like so:

- Course Name level 1
- Course Name level 2
- Course Name level 3 etc

I currently have the following in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'reorderByCourseLevel' );

function reorderByCourseLevel( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        if ( $query->is_tax() || $query->is_post_type_archive('subject') ) {
            $taxquery = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'course-level'
            );
            $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
            $query->set('orderby', 'title');   
            $query->set('order', 'ASC');
       }       
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything in my code..?

Comment: I think are trying to sort taxonomy terms, not posts by taxonomy. It can be confusing but they are very different concepts. I mean, you want to sort taxonomy terms by title, then group posts by taxonomy term (maybe with some specific order for posts within each group).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using wp\_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think I may have your answer in this blog post:
https://evowebdev.com/2017/05/using-a-dropdown-menu-to-filter-a-custom-post-type-with-custom-taxonomy/

This solution specifically uses select form element auto-populated with taxonomy terms to sort CPT posts (ie, rather than presorting posts with pre_get_posts, it lets site visitors sort by the taxonomy term[s] they select). If it's really important to pre-sort, this may not be an answer for you.

I could see it being useful, however, to allow people to select to view all courses of one of the levels.

That said, wouldn't the following presentation occur with alpha order?

- Course Name level 1
- Course Name level 2
- Course Name level 3