# show a post from a specific post format

Tags: theme-development, loop, query-posts, post-formats

I want to show 4 posts from a WordPress post type where 1 will show the post from the link format and the other 3 will be shown from another format.

So in this case, how to use the query or what method would be better if someone can give an idea?

[image: Related image]

Comment: you can use this function in the loop : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format

Comment: I used that but need a solid idea

Comment: please use  post template"WP Custom Post Template " plugin  post  wise design  create for own post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done, but it's quite some work, so I'm only going to give you the outline:

First, if you look at the last example under [taxonomy parameters of `wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) you will see that you can query post formats as a taxonomy. So you would look at something like this (untested) to get all posts in the link and quote formats:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-link' ),
            ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
            ),
        ),
    );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

At this point, there are still two things to do: order the array so the link format post comes first, and limit the amount of posts to 1 from link and 3 from quote formats. Unfortunately, [ordering by taxonomy in a query is not directly supported](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy). This also makes it difficult to select amounts of post per post format. The easiest way to solve this is by looping through `$query` twice using [`rewind_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts):

```
// Get one post with format link
while ($query->have_posts()) {
  $i=0;
  if (has_post_format('link') && $i<1) {
    // do your thing
    $i = $i+1;
    }
  }

$query->rewind_posts();

// Get three posts with format quote
while ($query->have_posts()) {
  $i=0;
  if (has_post_format('quote') && $i<3) {
    // do your thing
    $i = $i+1;
    }
  }
```

Note that you would still have to add some logic to account for cases where there are not enough posts to show.

Comment: it's not 100% work but I got 70% idea from it thanks @cjbj

Answer (score 1):

In the loop:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

endwhile;
```

In your theme you should have a directory "template-parts" and have these files:

```
content.php
content-link.php
content-another_format.php
```