# WP_query sort by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type “building”, another called “architects” and a custom taxonomy “date” associated to buildings. The taxonomy basically is the year in which the building was finished and buildings and architects are related to one another in the sense that architects make the buildings.

What I want to achieve is run a `wp_query` that will get all the buildings by a certain architect and sort them by date.

I have achieved the first part were I get all buildings by a certain architect but I cant figure out how to sort them by a custom taxonomy. I’ve read Otto’s answer here [Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy) on how sorting by taxonomy doesn’t make sense, but I believe in my case it does.

This is the code I’m using to get all buildings by a certain architect.

```
$buildings = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'building',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'suppress_filters' => 0,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'architect',
            'value' => '"'.$architect_id.'"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
));
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as taxonomy?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż That decision was made a long time ago, it made sense back then... it doesent seem entirely wrong to me either... how would you choose to store them?

Comment: And what exactly are you storing in that taxonomy? Is it a full date? Or just a year?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using wp\_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż its jsut a year, an integer