# How to order by taxonomy using wp_query

Tags: filters, taxonomy

I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy years, I would like order by this, I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Jose, as this post ([Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy)) says it doesn't make sense to sort by taxonomy.  A post could belong to multiple terms.

IF in your setup a post will only belong to one term, then consider making the taxonomy a custom field/meta key instead.  Then you will be able to sort by it.

Another way around (with risk of duplicated posts) is to get all terms in taxonomy in your preferred sort order and then get all posts belonging to each term.  A post may then appear twice in the list.

Comment: If you google sort posts by taxonomy terms, you'll find discussions on the issue.  EG: https://wpshout.com/sort-posts-taxonomy-terms/